# Anylogic RailCar Rectangle Color Change

Tags: anylogic

There is a rectangle inside a RailCar object representing a wagon which I need to change its color inside the Train object dynamically. The train includes a few railcars. I tried this code:

this.getCar(0).rectangle.setFillColor(maroon)

but I get an error which I am not sure how to address: "rectangle cannot be resolved or is not a field". Any idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what is getCar?

Comment: getCar( int i) returns a railcar of the train with a given index i starting from 0. A train has multiple railcars (wagons).

Comment: You need to tell us *where* you are writing this code. And you need to understand OOP principles, some hints here: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Comment: @Benjamin, in that link you sent there is a diagram/picture. In that, how you can access revenue variable inside Employee?

Comment: It depends *from where* you want  to access it, this is the "where am I" part. If you are in the `endOfFY` event code, as suggested, it is solution "A". Else, you need to apply the principles from this help page to navigate through the model hierarchy. 

Hence my original question: From *where* are you writing this code?

Comment: I am inside function "performance", and need to access "revenue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getCar(int i) returns an object of type 'agent'. To access elements inside of the RailCar agent you need to cast the returned value to a RailCar. The following code should work for this.

```
((RailCar)this.getCar(0)).rectangle.setFillColor(maroon)
```

I'm assuming here that you're calling this line of code from within your train agent.